# Add custom columns to Fullcalendar Listview

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using Fullcalendar V4, and i'm trying to add a new column after the title on Listview with the EventRender function.

I tried with some code using JQuery:

```
eventRender: function(info) {
    info.el.querySelector('.fc-list-item-title').append( "<td>Hello</td>" );
}
```

This do not produce anything.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a demo of your code from the question: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PoYzEgM - it **does** produce something, albeit perhaps not what you intended. I don't believe your statement "This do not produce anything" is correct.

But anyway, you're a) trying to append text instead of HTML, and b) trying to append it within another cell, rather than actually adding a new cell.

Since in a listView the event element `el` is a table row, we can insert a new cell into the row. This will do the job correctly:

```
eventRender: function(info) {
  var newCell = info.el.insertCell(3);
  var newText = document.createTextNode('Hello');
  newCell.appendChild(newText);
}
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/BaBzJXy

N.B. You might want to consider adding a new cell to the table header as well, to improve the visual effect.

Comment: @AliGajani Thanks for the notification. It seems that the site myjson.com which I used to mock the JSON event feed is no longer operating. If you simply replace that with some static event data then it should work anyway.

Comment: @AliGajani I updated the codepens with static data. Now you can see how they work.